# Why does hibernate/jpa set @OrderColumn field to null for a removed element in a mapped list before deleting it?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping

I'd like to map a tree structure of "chapters". Every chapter has a reference to its parent, and a ordered list (by "position") of subchapters.
With JPA 2.0, Hibernate 3.5, the entity "Chapter" looks as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Chapter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="position", nullable=false)
    private int position;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentChapter_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Chapter parentChapter;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderColumn(name="position")
    @JoinColumn(name="parentChapter_id")
    private List<Chapter> subChapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();

    public List<Chapter> getSubChapters() {
            return subChapters;
    }
}
```

The problem is, if one of the elements of `subChapters` is removed

```
// EntityManager em
Chapter parent = em.find(Chapter.class, 1);
subChapters = parent.getSubChapters();
subChapters.remove(1);
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
em.persist(parent);
tx.commit();
```

then Hibernate tries to execute this statement

```
update
    Chapter 
set
    parentChapter_id=null,
    position=null 
where
    parentChapter_id=? 
    and id=?
```

which fails because of the `NOT NULL` constraint of `position`.
If `@OrderColumn(name="position")` is removed, Hibernate doesn't update `position` (and therefore it works) and removes the (sub)`Chapter` afterwards.
What causes Hibernate to *first* update the future orphan and *then* remove it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a conceptual one, specially about the `position` property :-) It's a property of the list itself, not for the list-element (Chapter). So, I would do it differently:

```
@Entity 
public class Chapter {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Chapter parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
  @OrderColumn(name="position")
  private List<Chapter> children;
}
```

Note that you have two structs here: a Chapter and a List. The point is that the list state must also be persistent, but it's not related to the struct Chapter. So, it deserves a table for itself (and that's what Hibernate will try to do if you enable the "generate ddl").

You can see this example from their test suite:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/collection/list/

You'll see that they are not using annotations, but you can easily translate it :-)

Comment: Thanks partenon, but how can i access the position of a chapter then?

Comment: Well, the position is an implementation detail for the List struct. If you *need* to manipulate this property outside the scope of the List, then I'd say that you need another struct and map it using some non-standard way.